# Task in CD pipeline to edit or transform some files before every deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup CI/CD pipeline with Azure DevOps. My requirement is to setup task in release stage to edit or transform few files (XML and other text files according to the customer) before every deployment.

e.g. to edit `pom.xml` file to edit artifact id before every deployment.

How and where I can setup this task?

Answer (score 1):

In the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=replace&target=AzureDevOps) there are few extensions that can replace strings in files with other strings (the most popular is the "Replace Tokens"), you can install the extension and use it during the release pipeline.

Another option, write a small PowerShell script that replace the strings and in the release use the PowerShell task.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Suppose if I need to edit 4 files, Can i give it in the single "replace token" task with the path in next line or its require to add multiple "replace token" task for each file change

Comment: Look in the docs. In the "Replace Tokens" you have field "Target files" and you can put there few files.